# Can corns be grown the way in the VVitch?

Tags: realism, the-witch

[image]

In the movie, the VVitch, William is seen cut down corns; previously I thought corns had been harvested but it turns out they were farming corns in this way.

How realistic is this way of corn farming?

Comment: Oh yeah dude!  I'm big into 'corns!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A popular compromise to leaving the whole stalk is to chop it down to a height of 12 to 18 inches during harvest. This allows the shortened stalks to collect snowfall and cuts down on soil erosion, as well as keeps the corn residue in place, allowing for quicker breakdown of the residue into the soil.

In medieval times, this was regular practice

[image: medieval practice of cutting down corn before and after harvest]